# How can I save custom UserSession to cache after upgrading to ServiceStack 4?

Tags: servicestack, servicestack.redis

I used to be able to save my customer AuthSession to the cache, but since upgrading it only saves the properties on the IAuthSession interface, not my class CustomUserSession.

The code runs here:

```
public class AcmeUserSession : ServiceStack.AuthUserSession, IAcmeUserSession
{

    public override void OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session,   IAuthTokens tokens, Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
    {

     //code to update session object

     authService.SaveSession(this);     //*****HERE*****

    }
}
```

This code has not changed, but now when I look in redis at the saved object it only has properties from IAuthSession, not the custom properties from AcmeUserSession as it used to have.

Please help!

Thanks,

Richard

Comment: Can anyone give me a hint as to why this may have broken upon upgrade?

Comment: If you haven't, you'll need to add [DataMember] attributes on your Custom UserSession, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22018948/85785

Comment: That was it. Thanks mythz!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mythz answered this question perfectly. I quote him directly:

> Because AuthUserSession is a DataContract and attributes are now
>   inherited in v4, you also need to mark each member with [DataMember],
>   e.g:
>
> ```
> public class CustomUserSession : AuthUserSession
> {
>     [DataMember]
>     public string Hello { get; set; }
> }
> ```