# MVC4 and ServiceStack session in Redis

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, servicestack

I have a brand new MVC4 project on which I have installed the ServiceStack MVC starter pack (version 4.0.12 from MyGET) to bootstrap the usage of the service stack sessions.

In my `AppHost` my custom session is configured as:

```cs
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomUserSession(),
    new IAuthProvider[] {
        new CredentialsAuthProvider(config)
    }));
```

The custom session looks like this for testing purposes:

```cs
public class CustomUserSession : AuthUserSession
{
    public string Hello { get; set; }
}
```

And the `ICacheClient` is registered as a redis client:

```cs
// register the message queue stuff 
var redisClients = config.Get("redis-servers", "redis.local:6379").Split(',');
var redisFactory = new PooledRedisClientManager(redisClients);
var mqHost = new RedisMqServer(redisFactory, retryCount: 2);
container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(redisFactory); // req. to l
container.Register<IMessageFactory>(mqHost.MessageFactory);

container.Register<ICacheClient>(c =>
                        (ICacheClient)c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>()
                        .GetCacheClient())
                        .ReusedWithin(Funq.ReuseScope.None);
```

I have then created a `ControllerBase` which for simplicity loads and saves the custom session for each request:

```cs
public abstract class ControllerBase :  ServiceStackController<CustomUserSession>
{
    protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecute (System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        ViewBag.Session = this.UserSession;
        return base.BeginExecute (requestContext, callback, state);
    }

    protected override void EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        SaveSession(null);

        base.EndExecute(asyncResult);
    }
    public void SaveSession(TimeSpan? expiresIn = null)
    {
        Cache.CacheSet(SessionFeature.GetSessionId(), UserSession, expiresIn ?? new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0));
    }
}
```

I then modify the `Hello` property to read "World" in one of my actions, and I can clearly see with a breakpoint on the `SaveSession` method that the value has been properly. However, upon loading the page again and inspecting the loaded session, there's nothing set. Also, looking in the Redis database, the following blob is saved:

```
{
   "createdAt": "/Date(-62135596800000-0000)/",
   "lastModified": "/Date(-62135596800000-0000)/",
   "providerOAuthAccess": [],
   "isAuthenticated": true,
   "tag": 0
}
```

*It's not saving my custom property*. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong / missing?

=== UPDATE ===

If I change any of the properties from the base `AuthUserSession` the changes to those properties *are persisted* - so it would seem that SS somehow decides to disregard the properties from my concrete type.

Comment: I use the SaveSession Extension method in my SS service.  It does not exist in the ServiceStackController, but look at the code in it (https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/ServiceExtensions.cs) var sessionKey = SessionFeature.GetSessionKey(httpReq.GetSessionId());  I am just curious if both your method and this return the same value for the session key?

Comment: Do you use the "monitor" command in Redis to watch all of the changes, to see if your property is persisted at any point in time?  I'm curious if it is being set then overwritten for some reason?

Comment: Great tip with the redis monitor command. This verifies that one must use the GetSessionKey that you provided in the first comment - not just the sessionId. I can also see via the redis monitor cmd that my properties are _never_ sent to the redis server, so I'm starting to believe it's either a bug in SS or a misconfiguration on my side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because AuthUserSession is a DataContract and attributes are now inherited in v4, you also need to mark each member with `[DataMember]`, e.g:

```
public class CustomUserSession : AuthUserSession
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Hello { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: oh god I feel silly now. That works, thx. I also see now that the documentation actually state this - don't know how I missed that.